# How to sort a select option according to user input

Tags: php

Please I don't have any idea on how to achieve this so I need help. I have this code:

```
<select>
    <option>Sunday</option>
    <option>Monday</option>
    /* this option goes down to Saturday */
</select>
```

And the user have to choose an option which is inserted into the database, let's assume the user chooses Tuesday and wants to edit it later on. Now I want the option that will be visible to be Tuesday eg:

```
<select>
    <option>Sunday</option>
    <option>Monday</option>
   <option>Tuesday</option> /* this option will be the visible option before the user opens the selection */
</select>
```

And I want to achieve this through PHP and the variable assigned to the outputted database info is `$day` so `$day = 'Tuesday';` please how do I achieve this?

Comment: `<option selected="selected">Tuesday</option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this from within PHP you could do

```
<select>
    <option <?PHP echo $day=='Sunday' ? '"selected=selected"' : ''); ?>>Sunday</option> 
    <option <?PHP echo $day=='Monday' ? '"selected=selected"' : ''); ?>>Monday</option> 
    <option <?PHP echo $day=='Tuesday' ? '"selected=selected"' : ''); ?>>Tuesday</option> 

...

</select>
```

But it is not very elegant and gets difficult to code and more importantly **maintain** if the selection were to contain more that the seven days of the week.

So using an array of day names and a foreach loop and your `$day` variable containing the user selected day.

```
<?php
$dow = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday',
             'Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
?>
<select name="DayOfWeek">

<?php
    foreach ( $dow as $d ) :
        $sel = $d == $day ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        echo "<option $sel>$d</option>";
    endforeach;
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this is example and you can apply for all of select options

```
<select>
   <option <?PHP echo ($day=='Tuesday' ? selected : ""); ?>>Tuesday</option> 
</select>
```